# How to change Kubernetes metrics-server port?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

The default Kubernetes (K3S) installation (rather rudely) occupies port 443 with the metrics-server. I am able to patch the service to change the port but then kubectl does not know how to query metrics. Where do I change the port for the kubectl client?
Port 443 is not not in `~./kube/config` (only 6443 - the api port).

```sh
$ kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"
{"kind":"NodeMetricsList","apiVersion":"metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",...
```

```sh
$ kubectl patch service metrics-server -n kube-system --type='json' --patch='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/ports/0/port", "value":7443}]'
service/metrics-server patched
$ kubectl get --raw "/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1/nodes"
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Answer (score 1):

metrics-server has registered 443 with api-server during installation. Easiest way is [disable](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/install-options/server-config/#kubernetes-components) the bundled metrics-server and re-install with the service port set to 7443 [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/4b20c2d43e338d5df7fb530dc960e5d0753f7ab1/charts/metrics-server/values.yaml#L104), so the call out would reach the right port. If you are using the manifest, amend the port number [here](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/blob/4b20c2d43e338d5df7fb530dc960e5d0753f7ab1/manifests/base/service.yaml#L10).

Comment: Your suggestions just change the port of the service - this I have done successfully with `kubectl patch`. The Metrics API runs just fine on the new port 7443 but kubectl cannot contact it. Also, if the service is a ClusterIP, why/where is port 443 exposed on the Host?

Comment: kubectl does not connect to metrics-server directly.

Comment: Indeed, the port I changed is inside the cluster so that should make no difference externally. Something is listening on the host port 443 and forwarding it to cluster port 443. Headers say it's Traefik. I don' have Ingress so I guess it must be some kube system proxy.

Comment: Traefik is yet another bundled component of k3s.

Comment: I think my assumption that 443 on the host is the metrics server is incorrect. Something is listening on the port since `curl https://localhost:443` gives `404 page not found` but `sudo lsof -i -P -n | grep "443 (L"` shows nothing listening on that port.